# Could not find option 'storage_mode' in the list of available options: git_url, git_branch, type, app_identifier, username, keychain_name

Tags: ruby, fastlane

when I run this command to build the app:

```
bundle exec fastlane beta
```

shows this error:

```
[19:45:54]: ------------------------------
[19:45:54]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[19:45:54]: ------------------------------
[19:45:54]: Driving the lane 'ios beta' 
[19:45:54]: -------------------
[19:45:54]: --- Step: is_ci ---
[19:45:54]: -------------------
[19:45:54]: -------------------
[19:45:54]: --- Step: is_ci ---
[19:45:54]: -------------------
[19:45:54]: -------------------
[19:45:54]: --- Step: match ---
[19:45:54]: -------------------
Couldn't verify that spaceship is up to date
[19:45:55]: Variable Dump:
[19:45:55]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, :LANE_NAME=>"ios beta"}
[19:45:55]: Could not find option 'storage_mode' in the list of available options: git_url, git_branch, type, app_identifier, username, keychain_name, keychain_password, readonly, team_id, team_name, verbose, force, skip_confirmation, shallow_clone, workspace, force_for_new_devices, skip_docs

+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
| 2    | is_ci            | 0           |
| 3    | is_ci            | 0           |
| 4    | match            | 1           |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[19:45:55]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Could not find option 'storage_mode' in the list of available options: git_url, git_branch, type, app_identifier, username, keychain_name, keychain_password, readonly, team_id, team_name, verbose, force, skip_confirmation, shallow_clone, workspace, force_for_new_devices, skip_docs
(base)
```

this is my `storage_mode` config in `Matchfile`:

```
storage_mode("git")
```

I read the docs from here, and know that the default value of storage_mode is [git](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sync_code_signing/#parameters). this error makes me confuse. what should I do to fix this problem? This is my ruby version info:

```
$ ruby -v                                                                                                                                                                      ‹ruby-3.0.0›
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin19]
(base)
```

and this is my rubygem info:

```
$ gem -v                                                                                                                                                                       ‹ruby-3.0.0›
3.2.3
(base)
```